# PHP raising error about code outside of PHP begin / end characters

Tags: php, pastebin

I have a PHP page that keeps raising the error

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/zach/public_html/date/giftsent1.php on line 30
```

The funny thing is, line 30 is in the HTML. It is after the PHP end characters ( ?> ).

I have added the code to Pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/Dsh0KwdA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the ending double quotes in the query on line 18:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO gifts (`Gift`, `User`, `Type`, `From`, `Status`) VALUES ('$gid', '$val', '$ext', 'Pending');
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! I had been looking at that code for a couple hours now! Guess it just needed a fresh set of eyes! Thanks @Soumya92 and @Sarfraz !! I can't accept it for 7 more minutes, but I will when I can.